# Split polygon into parts adding attributes based on underlying polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, overlapping-features, splitting

I am trying to split one polygon in several parts adding varying attributes depending on the overlaying other polygons.

To illustrate what I am talking about: the yellow ring is a buffer zone around a marine protected area. I'd like to have this polygon split in different parts (but keep them in the same shapefile) where it overlaps with the light green area (the High Seas) and add an attribute for these areas to the buffer polygon indicating they are located in the High Seas (vs. exclusice economic zones, shown in blue).

[image]

I have a large number of shapefiles to do this with, if there is a plugin or batch process I'd be very happy to know.

Comment: So blue, green and yellow are different shapefiles? If yes, what is the role of blue shapefiles? Union of green and yellow layers possible do the trick, it will create new layer with combined both attributes and geometry.

Comment: Yes, all are different shapefiles. Will need to do the same for the blue shapefile or alternatively just copy all the data to the yellow one and then overwrite in appropriate areas with data from the green.